# How do I do a "starts with" query using SQL alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning to use SQL alchemy to connect to a mysql database. I want to pull records from the DB that start with a given string. I know that for simple equality all I need to do is this

```
queryRes = ses.query(Table).filter(Table.fullFilePath == filePath).all()
result = []
```

How do I do something like this?

```
queryRes = ses.query(Table).filter(Table.fullFilePath.startsWith(filePath)).all()
result = []
```

Maybe the query would look like this?

```
q = ses.query(Table).filter(Table.fullFilePath.like('path%')).all()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the pure SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE "string%"
```

The SQL alchemy is:

```
q = ses.query(Table).filter(Table.fullFilePath.like('path%')).all()
```

Answer (score 60):

SQLAlchemy has a [`startswith` column property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=startswith#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty.Comparator.startswith), so it works exactly as you'd think:

```
queryRes = ses.query(Table).filter(Table.fullFilePath.startswith(filePath)).all()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for SQLAlchemy versions >= 0.9 but not sure if 0.8 implemented `Column.startswith()` before 12/2013 yet.

Comment: SQLAlchemy.. What a library. Making queries like it is purely in Python

Comment: How to use a *list* of prefixes in the `startswith` function?

Answer (score 5):

If you need a case insensitive comparison, use [`ilike`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=startswith#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.ilike):

```
session.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.some_column.ilike('bla%')).all()
```