# Dynamic filter with startswith operator in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I did filter query for dynamically provided column and respective value.

```
from flask import request
filter_dict = {}
page = request.args.get('index', 1, type=int)
no_of_item = request.args.get('max', 10, type=int)
if request.args.get('first_name', type=int):
       filter_dict['first_name'] = request.args.get('first_name', type=str)
if request.args.get('city', type=int):
       filter_dict['city'] = request.args.get('city', type=str)
# Query
list_user_obj = User.query.filter_by(**filter_dict).paginate(page=page, per_page=no_of_item)
```

Now i would like to query all first_name start with 'jh' and city 'NY' suppose . How do i built query with more efficient way? Is there anyway to say `filter_dict` that while filtering `first_name` look for only start with 'jh' pattern.

Comment: `request.args.get('first_name', type=int)`: "I'm not a number, I'm a free man!"

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269260/how-do-i-do-a-starts-with-query-using-sql-alchemy

Comment: On a more serious note, `filter_by()` can only produce simple equality comparisons. If you need more complex criteria, you must use `filter()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä , Agree we can use filter() instead of filter_by(), But here i want build a query to perform  filter  using this condition ```User.first_name.startswith('jh') and city = 'NY'```.

Comment: Use both, chaining combines the added criteria with AND.

Comment: @IljaEverilä sorry i didnt get . Can you write the full query ? One more thing that is, if one of the  ```first_name or city``` filter value is not provided in the request then i need to filter based on provided filter value , so how can we do dynamic query ?

Answer (score 1):

i tried similar approach . Used filter() instead of filter_by(). It works for me.

```
from flask import request
filter_list= []
page = request.args.get('index', 1, type=int)
no_of_item = request.args.get('max', 10, type=int)
if request.args.get('first_name', type=int):
       filter_list.append(User.first_name.startswith(request.args.get('first_name', type=str))
if request.args.get('city', type=int):
       filter_list.append(User.city == request.args.get('city', type=str))
# Query
list_user_obj = User.query.filter(*filter_list).paginate(page=page, per_page=no_of_item)
```